# How to make canvas -element to fill and refill depending on the mouse position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, onmousemove

I have a script that follows Y-position of mouse and then fills the **width** of a `<canvas>` rectangle as the mouse moves down.

*In other words: The lower the mouse - the wider area of the canvas is colored, and vice versa.*

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mtsLwL5L/)

Now the problem is that canvas **only fills** and if the mouse is moved up, the filled area stays the same instead of shrinking.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the Canvas literally behaves as a canvas.

Your script paints the line green. It cannot un-paint the line.
you will need to have an equal opposite function that is constantly filling the line in Red from the other side.

you could achieve this a lot more easily without using Canvas.

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    var mouseY = e.pageY;
    $('.fill').width(mouseY);
});
```

see Example [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Panomosh/mtsLwL5L/1/)

You could also make this show both X and Y very easily like so:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    var mouseY = e.pageY;
    var mouseX = e.pageX;
    $('.fillY').width(mouseY);
    $('.fillX').width(mouseX);
});
```

See Example [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Panomosh/mtsLwL5L/2/)

Comment: @Shamppi Added another Example for you